# MFC VC++: Edit Control can't take [Enter] value

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am using a Edit Control on my MFC VC++ project, my issue is that while I am writing on Edit Control box it takes all input text in a single row. [Enter] key is not working while I am writing on it. If I paste some lines then it will show in original format means newline works here. Plz somebody help me.. !! thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use ES_WANTRETURN edit box style: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6e36b89f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

You can set this style in the resource editor, or in `dwStyle` parameter of `CEdit::Create` method, if edit control is created in the code.